# String Index Out Of Bounds Exception: String index out of range

Tags: java, binary-tree, infinite-loop

I am currently taking a text file and reading it into a string. I am then breaking the string up into words and adding each word onto a binary tree. for some reason I cannot get to the end of my string without getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 867183
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at Tester.breakIntoWords(Tester.java:71)
at Tester.it(Tester.java:21)
at Tester.main(Tester.java:11)
```

**Tester Class (has method breakIntoWords)**

```
public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Tester run = new Tester();
    run.it();

}

public void it() throws FileNotFoundException { 

    BTree theTree = new BTree();

    String str = this.readInFile();

    this.breakIntoWords(str, theTree);

    theTree.print();

}

public String readInFile() throws FileNotFoundException {


    String myFile = "";


    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(new File("Dracula.txt"));

    while(myScan.hasNext() == true) {

        myFile += myScan.nextLine() + " ";

    }

    return myFile;

}

public void breakIntoWords(String myFile, BTree theTree) {


    String nextWord = "";
    int position = 0;


    char next = myFile.charAt(position);
    next = Character.toLowerCase(next);

    // First trim beginning
    while (((next < 'a') || (next > 'z')) && !Character.isDigit(next)) {

        position++;
        next = myFile.charAt(position);
        next = Character.toLowerCase(next);

    }

    while(myFile.length() > position) {

        // Now pull only letters or numbers until we hit a space
        if(Character.isWhitespace(next)){

            position++; 
            next = myFile.charAt(position);
            next = Character.toLowerCase(next);

        }

        while(!Character.isWhitespace(next)) {

            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(next)) {

                nextWord += myFile.charAt(position);

            }

            position++; 
            next = myFile.charAt(position);

        }

        theTree.add(nextWord);
        nextWord = "";

    }

}

}
```

**BTree Class**

```
public class BTree {

private BTNode root;
private int nodeCount;


public boolean add(String word){

    BTNode myNode = new BTNode(word);

    if(root == null){

        root = myNode;
        nodeCount++;
        return true;

    }

    if(findNode(word) != null){

        myNode = findNode(word);
        int tmp = myNode.getNumInstance();
        tmp++;
        myNode.setNumInstance(tmp);
        return false;

    }

    BTNode temp = root;

    while(temp != null){

        if(word.compareTo(temp.getMyWord()) < 0) {

            if(temp.getRightChild() == null){

                temp.setRightChild(myNode);
                nodeCount++;
                return true;

            } else {

                temp = temp.getRightChild();

            }

        } else {

                if(temp.getLeftChild() == null){

                    temp.setLeftChild(myNode);
                    nodeCount++;
                    return true;

                } else {

                    temp = temp.getLeftChild();

                }

        }

    }

    return false;

}

public BTNode findNode(String word) {
    return mySearch(root, word);
}

public BTNode mySearch(BTNode root, String word) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if ((root.getMyWord().compareTo(word) == 0)) {
        return root;
    } else {
        if (word.compareTo(root.getMyWord()) > 0) {
            return mySearch(root.getLeftChild(), word);
        } else {
            return mySearch(root.getRightChild(), word);
        }
    }
}

public void print() {
    printTree(root);
}

public void printTree(BTNode root) {

    if (root == null) {

        System.out.print(".");
        return;

    }

    if(root.getLeftChild() == null && root.getRightChild() == null) {

        System.out.println(root.getMyWord());

    }

    printTree(root.getLeftChild());
    printTree(root.getRightChild());

}

public int wordCount() {

    return nodeCount;

}
}
```

**BTNode Class**

```
public class BTNode {

private BTNode rightChild;
private BTNode leftChild;
private String myWord;
private int numWords;
private int numInstance;
private boolean uniqueWord;
private boolean isRoot;
private boolean isDeepest;

public BTNode(String myWord){

    this.numInstance = 1;
    this.myWord = myWord;
    this.rightChild = null;
    this.leftChild = null;

}

public String getMyWord() {
    return myWord;
}

public void setMyWord(String myWord) {
    this.myWord = myWord;
}

public BTNode getRightChild() {
    return rightChild;
}

public void setRightChild(BTNode rightChild) {
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
}

public BTNode getLeftChild() {
    return leftChild;
}

public void setLeftChild(BTNode leftChild) {
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
}

public int getnumWords() {
    return numWords;
}

public void setnumWords(int numWords) {
    this.numWords = numWords;
}

public boolean isUniqueWord() {
    return uniqueWord;
}

public void setUniqueWord(boolean uniqueWord) {
    this.uniqueWord = uniqueWord;
}

public boolean isRoot() {
    return isRoot;
}

public void setRoot(boolean isRoot) {
    this.isRoot = isRoot;
}

public boolean isDeepest() {
    return isDeepest;
}

public void setDeepest(boolean isDeepest) {
    this.isDeepest = isDeepest;
}

public int getNumInstance() {
    return numInstance;
}

public void setNumInstance(int numInstance) {
    this.numInstance = numInstance;
}

}
```

Comment: If you want to debug, try putting `System.out.println` statements in the body of each loop, and see which one is still printing out when you lose all hope.

Comment: Once you hit whitespace you never update next.  The outer loop runs forever.

Comment: Isn't it better if you just use myString.split("\\s+")? And copy everything to the tree?

Comment: I read the title of this question as an existential *cri de coeur* and it was so much better that way.

Comment: Doing a quick search on SO for "String index out of bounds" returned 2,112 results. Do you think this question has been answer at least once before?

Comment: I have now fixed the infinite loop thanks

Comment: If the answers helped to fix your issue, please vote up. Concerning your new problem... think about the order of i) your validity check of the values for position and file.length(), ii) where you increment position and iii) what may then happen when calling `myFile.charAt(position)`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what that function is doing, and why you need that rather than `string.toLowerCase().split("\\s")`, or just `new Scanner(string.toLowerCase())`,

but when this condition is `true`:

`while(myFile.length() > position)`, and `next` is a whitespace,

`position` is not increased inside the loop, and `next` is not reassigned, so, you'll just keep spinning.

Comment: well the text file i am reading in is a copy of the book Dracula which when i use myString.split("\\s") creates an array so large i usually get a out of memory exception when trying to handle the arrays afterwards

Comment: You are already reading it with a `Scanner`, right? So, just use `Scanner.next()` instead of `nextLine()`, to get words one-by-one. That'll need even less memory, because you won't need to read the whole thing into a String first before even doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, one of your loops does not return. The problematic snippet is

```
while(myFile.length() > position) {
  while(!Character.isWhitespace(next)) {
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(next)) {
      nextWord += myFile.charAt(position);
    }
    position++; 
    next = myFile.charAt(position);
  }
  theTree.add(nextWord);
  nextWord = "";
}
```

The outer loop is executed as long `myFile.length()` is larger than `position`. `myFile.length()` is here fixed, so `position` has to change its value, by incrementing. Incrementing is done exactly at one place: when you do **not** have a white space at "position" next. If such a white space is found, the value of `position` is not changed and the outer loop will never exit.

To return from the loop, you have to increase the value of `position` even in case of a white space.